# max and min values that can be represented with a 5-digit

Tags: ieee-754, data-representation

How do I find max and min values that can be represented with 
a 5-digit number that is in base 13 assuming only positive integers 
are represented? then the answer needs to be in base 10.

does 5 digit number mean 5bits? Isn't the smallest number that
can be represented a zero and largest is 2^(N-1)?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like homework, but I'll bite anyway :)

5 digits probably means 5 digits, as in `12345`.

Base 13 means there are 13 possible digits where we as humans are used to calculate with 10.

We could represent the extra 3 digits with `A, B, C` so that the full range of possible digits is `0123456789ABC`. With this representation, it's clear that the smallest 5-digit value is `00000` and the largest `CCCCC`.

To convert `CCCCC` in base 13 to base 10 you do

```
((((C * 13) + C) * 13 + C) * 13 + C) * 13 + C 
= 
((((12 * 13) + 12 ) * 13 + 12 ) * 13 + 12 ) * 13 + 12 
= 
371,292
```

`00000` is of course zero in any base.

Comment: OMG it was this simple, thank you so much for answering this problem. and yeah.... this was my assignment....